# toString method is not calling. java

Tags: java, methods, invoke, tostring

I write following program to invoke the `toString` method, but it is not working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class findarea_class {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        findarea_class objtostring = new findarea_class(1.0,1.0);
        objtostring.setelements();
    }

    double width;
    double height;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    findarea_class()
    {

    }
    findarea_class(double width,double height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "width is: "+this.width+" and height is: "+this.height+"\n"
                +"The area is : "+getarea(width,height)+"\n"
                +"The perimeter is: "+getperimeter(width,height);
    }

    double getarea(double width,double length)
    {
        double area = width * length;
        return area;
    }
    double getperimeter(double width,double length)
    {
        double perimeter = (2 * length) + (2 * width);
        return perimeter;
    }
    double getwidth()
    {
        System.out.println("Please the width for calculation:");
        double inputwidth = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Width is:"+inputwidth);
        return inputwidth;
    }
    double getheight()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the height for calculation:");
        double inputheight = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Height is:"+inputheight);
        return inputheight;
    }
    void setelements()
    {
        double newwidth;
        double newheight;

        newwidth = getwidth();
        newheight = getheight();

        System.out.println("The new area is : "+getarea(newwidth,newheight));
        System.out.println("The new perimeter is `enter code here`: "+getperimeter(newwidth,newheight));
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean it is not invoking toString() method. Rest of the portion working fine but I want to invoke toString() method to display defaule value width = 1.0 and height = 1.0.

Comment: I cannot see even a single *UpperCase* letter in your code (leaving apart the ones where you're forced to). Please follow Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: Where would you expect `toString()` to be invoked?

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling toString(). Pass it to anything that can display it. Use:

```
System.out.println(objtostring.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks Whoppa. It is working now. :)

Comment: It is working now. The missing thing was, I was passing the parameter but not display method was missing. I got help from "Whoppa" and it is working now. :) :)

Comment: Glad I could help! If my answer was "best" then select the green checkmark near my post which will mark this as your "best answer".

Answer (score 1):

Your main method should print the object, or maybe you can put the println call in your constructor (although i'm not a big fan of that).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    findarea_class objtostring = new findarea_class(1.0,1.0);
    System.out.println(objtostring);
    objtostring.setelements();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override the `toString` method of `Object` class. Try this one.

```
@Override    
public String toString() {
        return "width is: "+this.width+" and height is: "+this.height+"\n"
                +"The area is : "+getarea(width,height)+"\n"
                +"The perimeter is: "+getperimeter(width,height);
}
```

and call it as `objectName.toString();`. In this case use something like this.`objtostring.toString();`